# stm32 not generating 100KHz on SCL with HMC5883L

Tags: stm32, i2c

I am trying to interface HMC5883L with STM32 L476RG NUCLEO. I have already tried to interface the sensor with arduino and it works perfectly and generates 100KHz on SCL line, which I verified using Logic Analyzer.

But now I am trying to interface it using STM32 I'm unable to do so, the SCL pin is not generating 100KHz, even I have set up the I2C for 100KHZ mode from STM32CUBEMX IDE.

Because of these above reasons I am getting NACK from slave

The code and logic analyzer output is attached below.

```
void HMC5883L_Init(void)
{   
     uint8_t kk = 0x1E;
     HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c3, kk<<1, 0x02, 1, 5000);
     HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c3, kk<<1, 0x00, 1, 5000);
}
```

[image]

[image]

I have tried using different I2c instances but didn't work.

I have tried both i2c1, i2c3 instance.

I tried using different i2c ports but didn't help.

Comment: A clock difference of 70kHz vs 100kHz will not affect the communication. There is likely another problem. The third parameter to `HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit` is incorrect. It must be a pointer, not a value. You probably got a warning in the build log.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, actually the internal pull up resistor were not enough, I had to connect around 4K ohms of external resistor to SCL line with VCC. Github repo and Logic Analyzer results - [github.com/abhisheeekkk/STM32_WITH_HMC5883L/tree/main](https://github.com/abhisheeekkk/STM32_WITH_HMC5883L/tree/main)